# Showing $\lvert \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R} \rvert = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: cardinals

What is the easiest way to show that
$$ \lvert \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R} \rvert = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) ? $$
I already know one cumbersome method, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler/cleverer way. If there's a technique that just uses basic cardinal arithmetic, that would be perfect.

**Another question I have is:**

Could using the heuristics
\begin{align*}
    \lvert \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}} \rvert \cong \lvert \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{R} \rvert \cong \lvert 2^\mathbb{R} \rvert &= \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \\
    \lvert \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \rvert \cong \lvert \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{Z} \rvert \cong \lvert \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} \rvert \cong \lvert \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z} \rvert \cong \lvert 2^\mathbb{N} \rvert \cong \lvert 2^\mathbb{Z} \rvert &= \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})
  \end{align*}
get me into a lot of trouble?

Comment: You need to refer to the *cardinality* of the power set of the reals in your equations. That is, put the absolute value bars around it also.

Comment: I am not sure why you call true statements (except for missing bars) heuristics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an injective map $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb N^{\Bbb R} $ given by $ A\mapsto \mathbf 1_A$, where $\mathbf 1_A(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in A\\0&x\notin A\end{cases}$.

We obtain an injective map $\Bbb N^{\Bbb R}\to \mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ by mapping $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb N$ to $\{\,g(x)+f(x)\mid x\in \Bbb R\,\}$, where $g\colon \Bbb R\to [0,1)$ is an injective map, e.g., $g(x)=\frac1{e^x+1}$.

Then $|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|=|\Bbb N^{\Bbb R}|$ follows by Schröder-Bernstein.